# How to use Flowable in RxJava 2?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

There is an introduction of new Flowable in RxJava2. How to use this in android. There was no Flowable in RxJava1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public class FlowableExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = FlowableExampleActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Button btn;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                doSomeWork();
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * simple example using Flowable
     */
    private void doSomeWork() {

        Flowable<Integer> observable = Flowable.just(1, 2, 3, 4);

        observable.reduce(50, new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(Integer t1, Integer t2) {
                return t1 + t2;
            }
        }).subscribe(getObserver());

    }

    private SingleObserver<Integer> getObserver() {

     return new SingleObserver<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.d(TAG, " onSubscribe : " + d.isDisposed());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Integer value) {
            Log.d(TAG, " onSuccess : value : " + value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG, " onError : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    };
}
}
```

I have a create a sample project to demonstrate the use of RxJava2. Here you can find the [sample project - RxJava2-Android-Samples](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/RxJava2-Android-Samples)

Comment: How do I learn all of features of RxJava2? It contains so many APIs. I don't know which is worth to learn for developing android apps.

Answer (score 1):

This is what it says in the documentations

> Practically, the 1.x fromEmitter (formerly fromAsync) has been renamed
>   to Flowable.create. The other base reactive types have similar create
>   methods (minus the backpressure strategy).

So you can use this in the same way as `fromEmitter` and `fromAsync`

[Rx.2 Documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0)